# mod pagespeed - CSS/JavaScript licenses

Tags: javascript, css, apache

The mod pagespeed module seems to remove the comments which contain the license inside of a given css/js.

Would  be possible to still minify the documents but retain the licenses?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, see RetainComments over at https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-comment-remove

Comment: RetainComments only applies to HTML not JS/CSS files.

Comment: Ah, your're right. the wildcard pattern is not currently used for retaining CSS or Javascript comments. You could file a feature request over at https://github.com/apache/incubator-pagespeed-mod/issues.